# How to un/break some Windows Store apps

Tags: windows-10, ntfs, modern-ui

I wanted to get rid of a bunch of Windows Store apps on my Windows 10 PC. So after Googling around for a way to do so, I settled on renaming a bunch of subfolders of this:

```
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps
```

in order to make Windows "lose track" of these apps. These are the names of the subfolders that I renamed or moved:

[image] [image]

And that worked. I only tried to rename (e.g. *break*) app names that I recognized. But apparently I was a bit overzealous since these stopped working, as well:

- Calculator
- Photos
- Voice Recorder

Which folders control those?

Comment: You'll need to give us a bit more information on what you did. Can you list all folders you renamed?

Comment: I added screenshots in the original post of all the subfolders I renamed or moved.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of removing or renaming folders, you may remove these Apps either with the standard Uninstall for the ones that allow it or using PowerShell for the other ones.
There is a really good article about this here: http://www.howtogeek.com/224798/how-to-uninstall-windows-10s-built-in-apps-and-how-to-reinstall-them/

I used it on my Windows 10 and it worked perfectly.

The last section (How to Reinstall All Built-in Apps) might work to get your apps back.

Comment: Would you be so kind to copy/paste the relevant information from that article into your post in case that article stops existing at some point in the future? If you'll do, I'll upvote your post.

Comment: I did try following that post prior to taking my more radical approach. I ran PS as Admin but still found that when I logged into the other users' accounts, the apps were still there. As far as reinstalling them per the suggestion there, I do not want *all* the apps back, only those three that I mentioned.

Comment: @Eliezer - If you want to remove it for all users there is an extra step you have to do.  If you read the article it explains how to restore specific default Windows Store applications

Comment: @Ramhound, I reviewed the article again but didn't see it explicitly discuss restoring specific apps. Based on what it said, I tried this in PS (run as admin)  ---  `Get-AppxPackage *soundrecorder* | Add-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage *photos* | Add-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage *windowscalculator* | Add-AppxPackage`  ---  but it didn't do anything: no errors and no effect. Not even for my account. (I tried logging out and back in.)
Any idea why?